# How to convert img inline styles for width & height to attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, amp-html

Currently my images are displayed from my CMS like so:

I'm working to create AMP pages and they do not accept image dimensions in style. AMP pages require:

```
<amp-img alt="stuff" src="welcome.jpg" height="200" width="203"></amp-img>
```

Is there a easy way with Rails/Ruby to make this conversion?

Comment: What are AMP pages? Can you add some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: AMP pages: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create/include_image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're doing this a lot, you can create a view helper like `image_tag`:

```
module AmpHelper
  include AssetUrlHelper

  def amp_image_tag(source, options={})
    options = options.symbolize_keys
    src = options[:src] = path_to_image(source)

    options[:width], options[:height] = extract_dimensions(options.delete(:size)) if options[:size]

    content_tag("amp-img", nil, options)
  end

protected

  def extract_dimensions(size)
    size = size.to_s
    if size =~ %r{\A\d+x\d+\z}
      size.split('x')
    elsif size =~ %r{\A\d+\z}
      [size, size]
    end
  end
end
```

This will work with the Asset Pipeline to provide asset hash / fingerprints in production, and works with the `:size` option:

```
amp_image_tag 'foo.jpg', size: '300x200', alt: 'Foo Bar!'

#=> <amp-img src="/assets/foo-abc123.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="Foo Bar!"></amp-img>
```